# Silly problem with UTF8

Tags: objective-c, plist

this is a silly n00b question but i just don't get it to work. I do believe that i need to convert to NSString and leverage "stringWithUTF8String:" but do not understand exactly how to implement it in this code so i get the right output in the NSLog. I have been looking around but it still do not work. The plist is correct.

My output is:

```
2010-11-07 21:43:00.419 plist_test[2984:207] Förbered och skriv  
2010-11-07 21:43:00.425 plist_test[2984:207] KLART  
2010-11-07 21:43:00.425 plist_test[2984:207] LÄS IN PLIST  
2010-11-07 21:43:00.427 plist_test[2984:207] array2: (  
    ETT,    
    "TV\U00c5",  ========Here is the problem, should be "TVÅ"    
    TRE,  
    FYRA  
)
```

Here is the code i am using.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

NSLog(@"Förbered och skriv");

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  
[array addObject:@"ETT"];  
[array addObject:@"TVÅ"];  
[array addObject:@"TRE"];  
[array addObject:@"FYRA"];  

[array writeToFile:@"/Users/PeterK/Desktop/plisttest.plist" atomically: TRUE];


NSLog(@"KLART");


NSLog(@"LÄS IN PLIST");

NSMutableArray *array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

array2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/PeterK/Desktop/plisttest.plist"];

NSLog(@"array2: %@", array2); ====here is the output


[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: are those strings serialized correctly onto the file?

Comment: looks OK to me: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/c5/index.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective-C String Literals are not strictly 7-bit ASCII, as your example has shown. However, you should avoid using anything but 7-bit ASCII for consistency and compatibility.

The follow work for simply loading strings using Unicode safely.

```
+ (id)stringWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error;
+ (id)stringWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error;
```

Localized String stuff is for multi-lingual interface stuff. Separating the text shown from the buttons shown, and such.

Comment: I get the following output: 2010-11-09 19:04:17.722 plist_test[684:207] LÄS IN PLIST
2010-11-09 19:04:17.729 plist_test[684:207] text: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
 <string>ETT</string>
 <string>TVÅ</string>
 <string>TRE</string>
 <string>FYRA</string>
</array>
</plist>

Comment: You're trying to load a plist file, which is xml content. so yes, that is the correct output for NSString. If you want to load that, you'd use NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile and then navigate the resulting tree.

Answer (score 2):

[Apple String Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/CreatingStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000148-CJBCJHHI) says objective c string literals in your code are strictly 7-bit ASCII.
(edit: they're not strictly 7-bit ASCII, but anything other than 7-bit ASCII means they're per-module and not linked into your static data section, which could lead to memory bloat.  in other words, unless it's a memory burden, go for it.)

You can load your strings from data via the [NSLocalizedString resources](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html) method.