# Objective-C : Problem with Swedish characters ÅÄÖ

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

Did ask a question about the same problem here: [Silly problem with UTF8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119656/silly-problem-with-utf8) but somewhat screwed up the thing so i do a new question and try to to it cleaner.

I do apologize if i ask this again.

I have been trying to get this to work but just can't get the result i want. I have tried the recommendations from my previous thread but still cant get it to work. As you understand i am very new at this and have really tried to read up on it.

Here is the scenario:

- NSMutableArray
- Store Swedish characters: "ÅÄÖ"
- NSLog the array
- Output is not correct

Code:

> NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
>   [myArray addObject: @"==="];
>   [myArray addObject: @"ÅÄÖ"];
>   [myArray addObject: @"==="];
>   NSLog(@"myArray: %@", myArray);

The output i get is:

> 2010-11-10 21:20:17.826 nsmutablearray_test[2976:207] myArray: (
>       "===",
>       "\U00c5\U00c4\U00d6",
>       "==="
>   )

The output i am looking for is:

> "===",
>       "ÅÄÖ",
>       "==="

As i have tested all kinds of things for this (simple) problem i would really appreciate if someone nice could show me the code to fix this?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple solution for you:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[myArray addObject: @"==="];
[myArray addObject: @"ÅÄÖ"];
[myArray addObject: @"==="];
NSLog(@"myArray: %@", myArray);

for (NSString *string in myArray) {
    NSLog(@"%@", string);
}
```

Output:

```
Swedish[3453:a0f] ===
Swedish[3453:a0f] ÅÄÖ
Swedish[3453:a0f] ===
```

Answer (score 3):

`\U00c5` is the unicode code for `Å`, so technically, that output is correct.  The string is still the same in memory, it's just that `NSLog` isn't outputting it how you're expecting.  But it's still the same string.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a problem with how NSLog handles UTF8 if I remember correctly. Try storing the description into an NSString first and then logging.

Either way, the data is correct, this is purely an NSLog issue.